# How do you add a double click event to a div in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Hello I'm new to extjs and I'm trying to add a double click event to a Div class in Extjs but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using:

```
source.getHeader().select('.config-panel-trigger').getEl().on('dblclick', function ()
```

as shown below

```
onContainerAfterRender: function (source) {

    // Add double click event handler on render
    if (source.getHeader() != null) {

        source.getHeader().select('.config-panel-trigger').getEl().on('dblclick', function () { //the line of code that isn't working

            Controllers.initialize(TV.constants.Constant.ContainerMenuOptions.Configure, function () {
                this.showContainerConfigurationDialog(source);
            }, this);
        }, this);
    }

    this.loadConfigData(source);
},
```

Comment: Doesn't sound very natural ... why do you want to listen a dblClick event in a div? What is the problem you are working on?

Comment: I agree but It's just a quick fix. I need to open up a configure panel on double click and I would like to adjust the following: source.getHeader().select('.config-panel-trigger').getEl().on('dblclick', function ()

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working"? As in, it throws an exception?

Comment: Maybe you should try using Ext.ComponentQuery.query('classname') function http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery if your div is inside a component

Comment: I think Ext.container.Container should be used only as container of other components. So you can add let just say Ext.panel.Panel in the container and then search your panel with Ext.ComponentQuery and then add double click

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in afterRender

this.mon(Ext.select('.config-panel-trigger'), 'dbclick', function(){....}, this);